# Can't get hold of single records from firebase query Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, future, bloc

I'm querying Firebase real time database and in the query itself  printing snapshot.value prints the correct entries values, but when I try getting single records converted to Item all values are null.
The forEach loop throws the error:
type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic, dynamic) => void' of 'f'
Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
await _databaseReference
          .child('Continent')
          .child('Europe')
          .child('Country')
          .child(countryDb)
          .child('Region')
          .child(regionDb)
          .child('City')
          .child(cityDb)
          .child('Catalog')
          .orderByChild('Product Category')
          .equalTo(query)
          .once()
          .then((snapshot) {
        print(
            ' local db result is $snapshot, value is ${snapshot.value}, item is ${Item.fromFirebase(snapshot.value).toMap().toString()}'); //item's values are null

        snapshot.value.forEach((childSnapshot) {
//          results.add(Item.fromFirebase(childSnapshot));
//          print('childSnapshot is : ${Item.fromFirebase(childSnapshot)}');
          print('childSnapshot is : $childSnapshot');
        });
        return;
      });
```

Item.fromFirebase:

```
static Item fromFirebase(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Item(
        itemId: map['Product Id'],
        brand: map['Brand'],
        itemName: map['Product Name'],
        category: map['Product Category'],
        price: map['Product Price'],
        description: map['Product Description'],
        vendor: map['Product Vendor'],
        code: map['Code'],
        isPromotion: map['isPromotion'],
        imageUrl: map['Product Picture Url']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The foreach type was wrong. As the values type are Map<dynamic,dynamic> passing in just one value doesn't match the type.

Passing in 2 values it does work as expected.

```
await _databaseReference
          .child('Continent')
          .child('Europe')
          .child('Country')
          .child(countryDb)
          .child('Region')
          .child(regionDb)
          .child('City')
          .child(cityDb)
          .child('Catalog')
          .orderByChild('Product Category')
          .equalTo(query)
          .once()
          .then((snapshot) {
        print(' local db result is $snapshot, value is ${snapshot.value}');

        snapshot.value.forEach((key, childSnapshot) {
          print('childSnapshot is : $childSnapshot');
          print(
              'childSnapshot is : ${Item.fromFirebase(childSnapshot).toMap().toString()}');
          results.add(Item.fromFirebase(childSnapshot));
        });
        return;
      });
```